# How to remove @Deprecated annotation using Proguard?

Tags: java, proguard, guava

My program uses md5 hash library provided by `guava`, but it is marked as `Deprecated` now.

In this article, it is said that [ProGuard will by default remove all annotations](https://medium.com/google-developers/practical-proguard-rules-examples-5640a3907dc9)

But I try Proguard, `@Deprecated` annotation isn't removed (`@Beta` annotation is removed). Which rule can help me to remove `@Deprecated` annotation?

My configure file is:

```
-dontwarn javax.annotation.**
-dontwarn javax.inject.**
-dontwarn javax.crypto.**
-dontwarn sun.misc.Unsafe
-dontoptimize
-dontobfuscate
-libraryjars 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_172\jre\lib\rt.jar'
-libraryjars 'D:\libs\animal-sniffer-annotations-1.14.jar'
-libraryjars 'D:\libs\checker-compat-qual-2.0.0.jar'
-libraryjars 'D:\libs\error_prone_annotations-2.1.3.jar'
-libraryjars 'D:\libs\j2objc-annotations-1.1.jar'
-libraryjars 'D:\libs\jsr305-1.3.9.jar'
-keepclasseswithmembers public class * {
    public static void main(java.lang.String[]);
}
```

Comment: I don't think the `@Deprecated` annotations should be removed. Instead of doing that, you should consider what would be replacement for deprecated stuff.

Comment: As per proguard By default, ProGuard treats annotation attributes as optional, and removes them in the obfuscation step. If they are required, you'll have to specify this explicitly:

-keepattributes *Annotation* 

Now the question is what would you achieve by removing deprecated annotation, rather you should focus bon alternate solution so that you won't have to use deprecated code.